# Android Bitmap too heavy error

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have the following problem that some of you must know on my android app :

> 3288-byte external allocation too large for this process.
>
> Out of memory: Heap Size=5959KB, Allocated=3922KB, Bitmap Size=18614KB
>
> VM won't let us allocate 3288 bytes

Facts :

- I'm creating a bitmap of the screen (so quite huge) and I manipulate it (changing size etc ...) for doing a flipping page animation.
- It crashes only on a desire HTC : on galaxy s2 and kindle fire, no problems.
- I'm already desallocating the current Bitmap everytime I create a new one with the following code :

  Bitmap old = this.bitmap;

  ```
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
  this.invalidate();
  if(old != null)
      old.recycle();
  ```
- I also tryied to call this function :

  public void recycle() {
          if (this.bitmap!=null)
              this.bitmap.recycle();
          System.gc();
          Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
      }

Severals time in my code, and sometimes it gets slightly better (like it crashes a little later), but that's still not good.

- I spent a lot of time on this problem, and I don't really get how to fix it. It's like on forum there is a lot of misinformation, so I'm kinda lost.

Thanks, ask for more precision.

Edit :

Here is a code called a lot :

```
//set the foreground image with the current day
                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(visibleLayout.getWidth(), visibleLayout.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                    visibleLayout.draw(c);

                    viewBitmapNext.setBitmap(b);

                    viewBitmapNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Where viewBitmapNext is an overwritted element of the View class. The setBitmap function is described above.

About the resizement, I do this line of code :

```
viewBitmapPrevious.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (iterator - ((totalWidth - iterator) - activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_right))/2), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Again, tell me if you you want to know more.

Comment: Are you doing this just once and running into the error? Or are you running this code multiple times?

Comment: Do you bind (attach) the bitmap to any Drawable or any element of the View hierarchy? If yes, you might need to set that reference to null as well. Note that recycle() does not release memory, it merely marks the bitmap to be released (this is useful in pre-HONEYCOMB devices where bitmaps are stored on a native bitmap heap). Calling gc() will certainly not help on your problem. Moreover, these bitmap size related crashes are often not directly related to the bitmaps themselves, but rather to some other error in your code (e.g. a Drawable leak due to an Activity leak via a static variable).

Comment: @ThomasW When I do not use recycle function, crashes the first time.

Comment: @ThomasCalc Interresting, yes I affect it to a view, I'll try your solution.

Comment: What sort of manipulations are you doing that creates a 18MB bitmap?

Comment: If you use Drawable.setBitmap(bitmap) or anything similar, you could try calling Drawable.setBitmap(null). This shouldn't be needed, because the new bitmap "overwrites" the previous reference next time anyway,but maybe there is not enough space in the memory for 2 bitmaps at the same time (and garbage collection / bitmap releasing comes too late). But this is too bad, because then memory is truly an issue,you might need a different approach for the whole thing (using smaller bitmaps, e.g. with memory-efficient scaling mechanisms -- the Android documentation contains useful resources for this).

Comment: @nEx.Software I'm just using createBitmap() function to have a Bitmap of the whole screen. I really need it by the way.

Comment: A screenshot should definitely not be anywhere near that big. You mentioned a resize, what does that look like?

Comment: @ThomasCalc as you predicts, it doesn't work (Drawable.setBitmap(null)). Would be really annoying to give up on my system (Big loose of time to think about an other solution and to do it), I'm more likely to give up cheap phones, unfortunatly. Thanks for help

Comment: @nEx.Software Some code in my post after edit explaining what I do exactly to create the bitmap and to resize it.

Comment: In your post, you write that you "call the code a lot". Where exactly do you draw that code? If you are trying to draw into the window (or other graphical element) of your Activity, you could try overriding its onDraw(Canvas) method instead. For example, you can subclass an own Drawable, and override its onDraw(Canvas) method. This link might help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29

Comment: I forgot to mention that the advantage of the above case is that you will get the Canvas as the argument of your overridden Drawable.onDraw() method. So you only need to add your subclassed drawable to your layout. Not sure if this is possible in your application, so it's just a suggestion that may or may not be useful for you.

Comment: @ThomasCalc A good advice, I'm on it, but do you think it has to do with the outOfMemory error problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be related, because I see you're explicitly calling the draw() method on some layout, and the official documentation mentions some criteria (such as full layout must be finished, etc.), so I'm not sure those criteria are met in your application. It also says you can override onDraw() when implementing an own View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29

Comment: Based on your code, currently my only guess is that instantiating a Canvas "a lot" (periodically, I guess) and sending it to a View.draw() is not OK. The documentation says: "It's recommended that you ultimately draw your final graphics through a Canvas offered to you by View.onDraw()." But just a guess, really. (The source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas)

Comment: @ThomasCalc Still on it. To answer your question, the code "called a lot" is called on every ACTION_MOVE of the finger. So that's really often.

Comment: You could measure how many ACTION_MOVE events you get per second.Allocating a brand-new full-screen bitmap very many times per second can be really resource-intensive.Again, I don't know your software architecture so I might be wrong,but you might eventually need to switch to a SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView. Pre-HONEYCOMB devices do not support HW rendering for Views,so in that case, GLSurfaceView might be the only one that can cope with such a demand.But this is off-topic, so it's only my suggestion for the worst case (which I hope won't happen and you'll be able to use your current approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. It will not be interresting for anyone, because it's a dumb error closely related to my project, but I say it anyway.

I actually had 2 errors :

- one loop creating elements infinitly.
- Two big pictures I put as a background after a certain action performed on a cheap phone ( I'm still on it but it should be easy to solve). I'll edit this answer when it's done.

To everyone that helped me, you couldn't find out the problem's solution (wasn't related to the bitmap-screen I do), but still it was helpful on it's way.

Thanks.